# Flutter: Test future builder

Tags: testing, dart, flutter, future

I want to test a function that has a Future builder. The function is:

```
     Widget loadWidget() {
        return new FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                double content = snapshot.data;
              return new Container(...)
           } else {
            return new Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
```

The test that I tried to write was something like:

```
testWidgets("should return a container",
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return MaterialApp(
          home: Material(
              child: Scaffold(
                  body:loadWidget());
    }));

    expect(find.byType(Container), findsOneWidget);
```

The `getData()` function seems to work, so I think that my problem could be that I don't know how to handle with the AsyncSnapshot.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Try calling `await tester.pump();` after the `await tester.pumpWidget(...)` to let the FutureBuilder resolve

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is stumbling over this question and looks for an answer like I did, I wanted to share a possible solution to this:

```
Completer<T> completer;
// ...
Widget loadWidget() {
  return new FutureBuilder(
    // substitute getData() here with the completer's Future
    future: completer.future,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        double content = snapshot.data;
        return new Container(...)
      } else {
        return new Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    }
  );
// ...
testWidgets("should return a container", (WidgetTester tester) async {
  completer = Completer<T>(); // initialize Completer here!
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: loadWidget()
          )
        )
      );
    }
  );
  // Interesting part comes here:
  // you can provide a Future or some piece of data
  // as parameter of the complete method
  completer.complete(getData()); // this "completes" (resolves) the future and returns the data you provided
  await tester.pump(Duration.zero); // still necessary
  expect(find.byType(Container), findsOneWidget); // should succeed now
});
```

You should wrap your `Future` in a `Completer` and manually complete the `Future`. Have a look at https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/v0.3.3/packages/flutter/test/widgets/async_test.dart. This is where I took it from.
Since I'm fairly new to Flutter I don't really know why you have to initialize `completer` in the `testWidgets` method. Maybe it has something to do with the `testWidgets`'s scope.